# Map one object contain list to list myDto object

Tags: c#, automapper

Object from other application:

I can get it:
one object like this:

```
public MessageSendTMP {get; set;}
```

containing example:

```
public string title {get; set;}
public string Author {get; set;}
public string Date {get; set;}
.....10 more and
public List<Guid> IdPlayers {get; set;}
```

MessageDto is a simple object with 20 properties like data, author, name, title etc... and IDplayer the message is for.

In my aplication i have to save it in the db in message_table.
I would like to use automapper, where would i map MessageSendTMP to MessageDto with "ForMember" in createMap but i dont know how.
I would like to have it before saving like this:
List< MessageDto > dataToSave with this many records as size IdPlayers in MessageSendTMP

Example:

```
MessageSendTMP {
    title = "titleMessage",
    Author = "John",
    Date " "17-04-2021",
    .....
    IdPlayers = [2, 3, 10]
}
```

And I'll get list MessageDto about size 2:

```
[0] = { title = "titleMessage", Author = "John", Date " "17-04-2021", ....., IdPlayer = 2},
[1] = { title = "titleMessage", Author = "John", Date " "17-04-2021", ....., IdPlayer = 3},
[2] = { title = "titleMessage", Author = "John", Date " "17-04-2021", ....., IdPlayer = 10}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use use `ITypeConverter` for custom mapping:

```
public class Message
{
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Author { get; set; }

    public string Date { get; set; }

    public List<Guid> IdPlayers { get; set; }
}

public class MessageDto
{
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Author { get; set; }

    public string Date { get; set; }

    public Guid IdPlayer { get; set; }
}

public class MessageConverter : ITypeConverter<Message, IEnumerable<MessageDto>>
{
    public IEnumerable<MessageDto> Convert(Message source, IEnumerable<MessageDto> destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        foreach (var playerId in source.IdPlayers)
        {
            var msg = context.Mapper.Map<MessageDto>(source);
            msg.IdPlayer = playerId;

            yield return msg;
        }
    }
}
```

Then:

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(options =>
        {
            options.CreateMap<Message, IEnumerable<MessageDto>>(MemberList.Source).ConvertUsing<MessageConverter>();
            options.CreateMap<Message, MessageDto>();
        });

        var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

        var message = new Message
        {
            Author = "auth",
            Date = DateTime.Now.ToString(),
            title = "title",
            IdPlayers = new List<Guid> { Guid.NewGuid(), Guid.NewGuid(), Guid.NewGuid() }
        };

        var result = mapper.Map<Message, IEnumerable<MessageDto>>(message);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would ignore `IdPlayer` property and register a mapping that copy other properties. Then I would just loop over `IdPlayers` collection and in every iteration I would create new `MessageDto` using AutoMapper and set `IdPlayer` property manually.

The downside is that your mapping registered in AutoMapper profile is not complete. If your mapping is very simple and you don't use advanced AutoMapper features, maybe creating your own mapping using reflection is a better option for you. See: https://dejanstojanovic.net/aspnet/2014/september/simple-object-mapper-using-reflection/